# Any good plotting library for massive data analysis in C/C++?

Tags: gratis, linux, library, c, plotting

I use GNUPLOT and PGPLOT for plotting my data in C/C++. But these are ridiculously slow when the data size becomes huge. So I want a plotting library that can give me a fast response even if I plot a million points on it. Any recommendations?

Requirements:

- It should be freeware.
- It would be good if it runs on all POSIX systems.
- It should run at least on CentOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the library supposed to be free or open source? Which operating systems has it to support?

Comment: @ComFreek added the requirements in the question

Comment: I don't think this is possible.
I think you are running up against the problem that this is not a tractable problem.
because plotting time is linear with respect to number of points.
I would be very surprised if GNUPLOT or PGPLOT were not already using the most optimal algorithm.

It isn't even parallelisable, unless the data is presorted -- sorting would take longer than plotting.

Comment: I found ploticus to be an order of magnitude faster than gnu plot for something I was working on a few years ago, but I don't really know the current status.

Comment: @technosaurus Thanks I will check it out.